# What kind of light is used in this photograph?

Tags: lighting, product-photography

[image: product image of earrings]

What kind of light is used in this photography?

Comment: What do you mean by "what kind of light"? Do you mean "how was the light positioned?" or do you mean "was this taken under fluorescent lights?" Or something else entirely?

Comment: I think if this was asked more as a "how do I reverse-engineer what lighting was used?" it might be a _much_ better question. As it is, we can only throw you a fish instead of teaching you how to fish. Consider editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess - though not much of an answer - is...

Broad & high.

Looks like it could be a single large softbox above the display & slightly left of centre.

Comment: The soft shadows going down also seem to show that the light is slightly behind the object. The fabric appears ruffled on a slight angle and the jewelry placed on it, with the light slightly behind so that the shadows extend downward.